# Setting up Search for a specific site collection

Tags: search-results, search-scope

Say I have a site collection "Legal". Paralegals from outside (with temp AD account, via citrix) will be accessing the Legal site collection (http://portal.someISD.edu/Legal).

I have about 40 document libraries. (excluded the forms but did not seems help). Also need to exclude everything but document libraries.

I would like to make sure result are only coming from legal site collection when users  (paralegals) performs a basic search that shows up on the header area.

Not sure if SP will security trim the result since they will will not have access to any other 79 site collections that are hosted on the portal web app.

I added a scope for legal site in CA > Search App > and I am comfortable configuring advance search. Just need to make users' search stays within the boundary of legal site collection.

========== UPDATED ==========
Created search scope (thru C

1. Created Search Scope thru CA

   A) Add IsDocument=1 include; Folder=url/Lists exclude; Folder=Forms exclude; Folder=doclib include\
2. From the site collection > Site Settings > Search Scope > Only picked the new Scope for both basic and adv search
3. Results are good except "forms/allitems.aspx" shows up in the result page.

Comment: Added a exclusion rule for the scope I created but /Forms/AllItems.aspx still shows up in the result page.

Answer (score 1):

If things are not as they are expected with search results I would try a full crawl and id that does not work, reset the crawl index, I had issues with results before and index rest fixed them. You can do this from the Search Service admin interface.

As for the results, users will not see results they don't have permission to, it will be security trimmed.

Here is more info on that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981314.aspx

Comment: Does advanced search ignores default scope that is being setup at the site collection level? or I am force to edit the XML?

Comment: You can redirect the user to a search results page which has the Search Core Results Web Part bound to a specific scope.   You can change the scope for your search results page Search Core Results Web Part and here is a link showing how to do it, this way, only the results from your scope will be displayed: http://sharepointers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/change-default-search-scope-of-your.html

Comment: Not applicable for SP2010. Scope property isnt listed for the Search Core Results web part.

Comment: Here is a link which has an image showing the Scope setting under Locations group, expand the Location collapsed group to see the Scope setting:  http://red1s.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/sharepoint-2010-adding-multiple-search-core-results-to-one-page-with-different-result-sets/